# How to post to a sign-in form with Flurl

Tags: c#, flurl

I want to represent a signin in a url(i.e. eclass.aueb.gr) to get the source code of the next page(the portfolio of the user).
What i have now, is the code from documentation...

```
var response = await "https://eclass.aueb.gr/index.php".PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
            {
                uname = "name",
                pass = "pass"
            });
```

Currently the response is the code of the url itself.

Comment: "Currently the response is the code of the url itself." Not sure what you mean by that exactly.

Comment: The source code of the site, like if I made a simple httpRequest. What if I created an issue on GitHub, to improve documentation...?

Comment: And when you sign in from a browser you land on a portfolio page? What is the URL of that page?

Comment: https://eclass.aueb.gr/main/portfolio.php but the main goal is to fill the form and click the sign in button from c#. Can this library do this?

Answer (score 2):

The page is most likely following the [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (as it should, per best practices), so the fact that the response you are getting is the original page just means you didn't code the redirect part. Do you need to? Not if all you need to do is log in. Are you successfully logged in? Hard to say for certain. `response.StatusCode` *might* be "Unauthorized" (401) if it failed (you could test it against invalid credentials), but since you're scraping a site designed for browsers and not automation (like an API), you might have to pick through that big string of HTML you got back and look for error messages. There again, see what happens in a browser when you try to log in with invalid credentials. And remember - [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) are your friend, particularly the Network tab in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your time. We should develop this feaure in Flurl(i can contribute). I solved it with a webview and invoked javascript.